# Convert Web Friendly Django app to a Mobile friendly django app

Tags: python, django, user-interface, package

I've made a desktop-friendly django app and would prefer not to have to rewrite all of the html/css to allow proper view on mobile browsers.

I'm on django 1.5 and python 2.7

Is there a package or library or quicker way to efficiently create a mobile version of my django (web) app instead of having to re-write a whole new template with html/css ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word, no.  You're going to have to rewrite most of your templates to be "responsive" to smaller (mobile) screen sizes.

I'd recommend [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) for your HTML5/CSS3 framework.  Easy to get started, easy to extend.

Comment: What is your opinion of jQuery mobile? I'm trying to get all the opinions before jumping on one.

Comment: (My opinions): jQuery Mobile is a good library with lots of mobile-friendly widgets.  It's all about looking like a smartphone but it doesn't expand to a desktop screen very well.  It tries to "own" the screen with header, footer, toolbar, etc., and that can make it hard to customize.  Bootstrap is closer to that sweet spot for supporting multiple screen sizes.

Comment: I'd like to add: if you've constructed your html correctly, the only thing you would have to change is screen size-sensitive CSS. Meaning that you would really only have to _add_ CSS rather than recreate it.

Comment: Good point @OozeMeister - my css validates as valid CSS3 first try. Thank you both for your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Use the bootstrap. I developed the django app too using the bootstrap and it works fine in all smartphone, tablet and desktop devices.