# How to build Django application that renders to both web client and mobile app

Tags: python, django

I am building a web application in django, and so far I have been using django templating for rendering to a web browser. However, I intend to extend the application for mobile app as well. I read that the best way of doing is to build a RESTful application. I know how to do it in django as it's very easy using django-restframework, however, I don't really see how to build an app that will render to both a web browser using templating and a web app with a simple JSON response. Do I need to check in my views the client type and use a different response depending whether it is a web or mobile app ? or is there another way to do so. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Surely your mobile app will use specific API URLs?

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I don't really know how to do it actually. You mean that the mobile app should use different URLs ? and in this case the view would be different for a mobile app or web browser ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666243/convert-web-friendly-django-app-to-a-mobile-friendly-django-app?rq=1) - gives hint on making web-friendly Django app, mobile friendly (responsive). TL;DR, try Twitter Bootstrap or a similar UI framework/toolset.

Otherwise, if you intend to have a mobile experience that mimics your web app, there are two ways to ago about it:

1. Write a native UI in the language supported by your chosen mobile OS (e.g Java for Android). Search online for tutorials on how to make REST API calls in your chosen language, and then expose the REST APIs you said you already have, to these client-side calls.
2. If you designed your web-app such that the front-end is somehow decoupled from the back-end (for example, your front-end can already interact with the back-end purely via API calls or AJAX), or if you can make this happen, then, you can bundle your front-end, using such a toolset as Cordova, PhoneGap, etc, and again, depending on where you wish to run your mobile app, having the front-end UI render in a mobile hybrid app (native-engine, renderig web UI).

There are possibly other approaches - e.g, my own work in cross-platform development led me to develop [Project Okot](https://nuscribes.com/scribes_app/book/40/read/?#chapter-500), whose [Studio](https://studio.nuchwezi.com) allows you to design apps once (drag-and-drop), and have them render on mobile and web without any further coding!

The above are ideas to get you started... Otherwise might have even better solutions.

Comment: Thank you nemesisfixx. So one of the way is to build the django app to render JSON responses. To write my html web pages independently using AJAX to query and get JSON data, and build the mobile app UI independently to do the same thing. Without using django templating to let the backend separate from the front. Right ?

Comment: @Spider, yes, that's exactly what I recommending in #1&2 - the only difference is in how much u wish to leverage the front-end code as well. #1 lets u simply share just the API (back-end) between the web and mobile projects. #2 explores how to share even the front-end code as well.

Comment: Thank you nemesisfixx. That helps a lot !